# Request Mapping Spring + Hibernate Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having issues trying to map requests in my new spring hibernate application. I have never set one of these up before so I am kind of a newbie. I just got hibernate configured properly and the application runs, but when I try to hit one of my controllers via POSTMan, it doesn't work. I am assuming when it does it's component scan it is not finding the RequestMappings.

Specifically, I am testing with /greeting/method0 in the GreetingController class

All of my code is linked here: https://github.com/cfeher/Party-App/tree/0.0.x/Api

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Specifically which controller is failing? What URL are you using?

Comment: Hey, I am trying /greeting/method0 inside the GreetingController Class

Comment: Ah, it looks like you're missing a web.xml. Take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: @hoipolloi, Chris is using spring-boot. Not a regular spring mvc webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your componentscan is not scanning your controller as it is sitting in a different package. For your example to work, add base package to component scan as below. This should help to scan.

```
@ComponentScan("org.mobiengineering")
```